# how to make a blocking recv call

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, recv

it may be a strange request, but, actually, I would like make my call to recv() *blocking*.

It appears that it should be blocking *by default*, but for me, it is not, and I can't find any way to make it.

I have a very simple server application, "*open socket - bind - wait for connection - receive*" on one hand,

and, on the other hand, a simple "*open socket - connect - send*" client application.

They communicate on LocalHost.

Server :

```
int clTcpServer::openSocket(void)
{

  this->__iLocalSocketId = socket(AF_INET,      //stand for IPV4
                                  SOCK_STREAM,  //using TCP protocol
                                  0);           //no specified / ip protocol
  return 0;
}

int clTcpServer::openServer(uint16_t u16Port)
{
  this->__strServerInfo.sin_family = AF_INET; // stand for IPV4
  this->__strServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Listen to any address (no filter)
  this->__strServerInfo.sin_port = htons(u16Port);

  if(bind(this->__iLocalSocketId, (sockaddr *)&this->__strServerInfo, sizeof(this->__strServerInfo)) < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "TCP server - ERROR - Can't bind socket to port " << std::dec << (int)u16Port << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::cout << "TCP server - Server opened" << std::endl;

  listen(this->__iLocalSocketId, 3);

  return 0;
}

int clTcpServer::waitForConnection(void)
{
  int iClientIpInfo;

  char* pcClientIp;

  std::cout << "Waiting for connection ..." << std::endl;

  iClientIpInfo = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  this->__iDistantSocketId = accept(this->__iLocalSocketId,
                                    (sockaddr *)&this->__strClientInfo,
                                    (socklen_t*)&iClientIpInfo);

  if(this->__iDistantSocketId < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "TCP server - ERROR - Connection refused" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  pcClientIp = inet_ntoa(this->__strClientInfo.sin_addr);
  std::cout << "Connection accepted from " << pcClientIp << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

int clTcpServer::receiveDataBuffer(void * pvidBuffer, size_t sizeMaxBufferSize)
{
  int iRecvSize;

  iRecvSize = recv(this->__iDistantSocketId, pvidBuffer, sizeMaxBufferSize, (int)0);

  if (iRecvSize < (int)0 )
  {
    std::cout << "TCP server - ERROR - Recv failed" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  return iSentSize;
}
```

Client :

```
int clTcpClient::openSocket(void)
{
  /* Create a new socket for client comm. */
  this->__iSocketId = socket( AF_INET,      //stand for IPV4
                              SOCK_STREAM,  //using TCP protocol
                              0);           //no specified / ip protocol

  if (this->__iSocketId == (int)-1)
  {
    std::cout << "TCP client - ERROR - Can't open Socket" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int clTcpClient::connectToServer(std::string stgIpAddress, uint16_t u16Port)
{
  /* configure server info according to parameters */
  this->__strServerInfo.sin_family = AF_INET; //stand for IPV4
  this->__strServerInfo.sin_port = htons(u16Port);

  /* Retrieve IP addr*/
  this->__strServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(stgIpAddress.c_str());

  /* Try to connect to the server */
  if (connect(this->__iSocketId,
              (sockaddr*)&this->__strServerInfo,
              sizeof(this->__strServerInfo)) < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "TCP client - ERROR - Can't connect to " << stgIpAddress << ":" << std::dec << (int)u16Port << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::cout << "TCP client - Connected" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

int clTcpClient::sendDataBuffer(const void *kpvidData, size_t sizeDataLength)
{
  ssize_t sizeSentSize;

  /* Send the buffer */
  sizeSentSize = send(this->__iSocketId, kpvidData, sizeDataLength, (int)0);

  if (sizeSentSize < (ssize_t)0 )
  {
    std::cout << "TCP client - ERROR - Send failed" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::cout << "TCP client - " << (int)sizeSentSize << " byte(s) sent." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is working fine, but recv() here is not blocking. If I call it (after having initialized all the stuff, of course), if there is nothing to receive, the function returns 0, as "0 byte received", and that's all.

It means If I want to put this recv function in a loop, CPU is working 100% to receive ... nothing.

What's wrong here ?How can I make it **blocking** ?

Thank you

Comment: Unless you are actually requesting 0 bytes be read, then a return value of 0 from `recv()` means the connection has been gracefully closed by the remote peer.  This is documented behavior. You are supposed to STOP READING and close your socket.

Comment: yes, I read that, but I do not close it. On client side I "open" then "connect to server", then while(forever).
Is it possible for the socket to "close itself" alone ?

Comment: When `recv()` returns 0 on the client side, it means the server closed the connection on its end, which sends a `FIN` packet to the client, which causes `recv()` to return 0 to notify your code so it can close its open socket handle. Stop looping if `recv()` returns 0, or if it returns -1 and `errno` reports anything other than `EAGAIN`, `EWOULDBLOCK`, or `EINTR`.